# /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: mysql

```
when i am installing the mysql using(sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-clien) in ubuntu 11.04 i get an error like this:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
how should i avoid this error
info:
Trying to install  libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb seperately also leads to an error
 how can i avoid this.
thanks in advance
the error code as follows
(Reading database ... 214333 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libdbi-perl (from .../libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/dbiprof', which is also in package perl-dbi 1.52-3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously deselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.016-1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-client-core-5.1.
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.1 (from .../mysql-client-core-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-client-5.1.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.1 (from .../mysql-client-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-core-5.1.
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-core-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server-5.1.
Unpacking mysql-server-5.1 (from .../mysql-server-5.1_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-client.
Unpacking mysql-client (from .../mysql-client_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbi-perl_1.612-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a file collision between the official Debian package `libdbi-perl` and a third-party package called `perl-dbi`. There is no `perl-dbi` package in Debian. You should probably remove it (`dpkg -r perl-dbi`) but first, try to figure out where it came from with `apt-cache policy perl-dbi`